# How to use multiple axes with finplot as a widget in layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I have used [finplot as a widget in layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64074217/finplot-as-a-widget-in-layout) - it works very well:

```
self.tab1.fplt_widget = pg.PlotWidget(
    plotItem=fplt.create_plot_widget(self.window())
)
```

What I'd like to do is use the above widget, but also have multiple axes, ie:

```
ax, ax1 = fplt.create_plot_widget(self.window())
```

How would this work?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I just used a wrapper of the `pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget`:

```
class ChartGraphWidget(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.centralWidget.installEventFilter(self)
        self.ci.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.ci.setSpacing(-1)

        self.show_maximized = True  # maximize
        sx0 = axs = fplt.create_plot_widget(
            master=self, rows=4, init_zoom_periods=50)

        ...
```

I also discovered that a single `pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget` with multiple axes is much faster than an axis for each `pyqtgraph.dockarea`.